# WPAS wordpress search

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WPAS (Wordpress Advanced Search) and i'd like to search by tag_id name and not slug.

My wp-admin link look like:

```
wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=leasing-auto&tag_ID=3&post_type=autoturism
```

As you can see **tag_ID=3** and it looks like:

```
Name : a-name
Slug : a-name-something-that-i-dont-want-to-appear
```

Problem:

My search needs to be by name and not by slug.
At the momment if i write `a-name` will throw an error as it doesnt find, buuut, if i search for `a-name-something-that-i-dont-want-to-appear` will give me the expected result...

Can i use WPAS to search by name and not by slug?

**Code:**

```
function cautare_simpla() {

    if(isset($_COOKIE['carsno'])) {
        $ppage = $_COOKIE['carsno'];
    }
    else{
        $ppage = 24;
    }
    $args = array();

    $args['wp_query'] = array('post_type' => 'autoturism',
        'category__not_in' => array( 83, 84 ),
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppage
    );

    $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'taxonomy',
        'taxonomy' => 'leasing-auto',
        'format' => 'select-group',
        'nested' => 'true',
        'operator' => 'IN',
        'class' => 'selectpicker',
        'pre_html' => '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"><label>Model Masina</label>',
        'post_html' => '</div>',
        'attributes' => array('data-show-subtext' => true, 'data-live-search' => true ) ,
        'term_args' => array('hide_empty' => true,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'track' => true,
            'order' => 'ASC')
        );

    $args['fields'][] = array( 'type' => 'meta_key', 
        'format' => 'select',
        'class' => 'selectpicker',  
        'pre_html' => '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"><label>Culoare</label>',
        'post_html' => '</div>',                           
        'meta_key' => 'culoare',
        'allow_null' => 'Toate',
        'values' => array(
            'Alb'=> 'Alb',
            'Albastru'=> 'Albastru',
            'Alta'=> 'Alta',
            'Argintiu'=> 'Argintiu',
            'Auriu'=> 'Auriu',
            'Bej'=> 'Bej',
            'Galben'=> 'Galben',
            'Grafit'=> 'Grafit',
            'Gri'=> 'Gri',
            'Maro'=> 'Maro',
            'Metalic'=> 'Metalic',
            'Negru'=> 'Negru',
            'Oranj'=> 'Oranj',
            'Rosu'=> 'Rosu',
            'Sky'=> 'Sky',
            'Verde'=> 'Verde',
            'Violet'=> 'Violet'
            ), 
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );  




    $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'html',
        'value' => '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 range-box" data-range-name="an_fabricatie">');

    $args['fields'][] = array( 'type' => 'meta_key', 
        'meta_key' => 'an_fabricatie',
        'data_type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'inputs' => array(
            array(
                'format' => 'number',
                'value' => '',
                ),
            array(
                'format' => 'number',
                'value' => '',
                )
            )
        );  

    $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'html',
        'value' => '<label>An fabricatie:&nbsp; <span id="an_fabricatie-label">2000-2016</span></label><input type="text" class="base-input" id="an_fabricatie-input" value=""  data-provide="slider"  data-slider-tooltip="hide" data-slider-min="2000" data-slider-max="2017" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[2002,2015]"/></div>');



    $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'html',
        'value' => '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 range-box" data-range-name="pret">');

    $args['fields'][] = array( 'type' => 'meta_key', 
        'meta_key' => 'pret',
        'data_type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'inputs' => array(
            array(
                'format' => 'number',
                'value' => '',
                ),
            array(
                'format' => 'number',
                'value' => '',
                )
            )
        );  

    $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'html',
        'value' => '<label>Pret:&nbsp; <span id="pret-label">3000-90000</span> €</label><input type="text" class="base-input" id="pret-input" value=""  data-provide="slider"  data-slider-tooltip="hide" data-slider-min="3000" data-slider-max="90000" data-slider-step="1000" data-slider-value="[5000,40000]"/></div>');


    $args['fields'][] = array( 'type' => 'meta_key', 
        'format' => 'select',
        'class' => 'selectpicker',  
        'pre_html' => '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"><label>Cutie Viteze</label>',
        'post_html' => '</div>',                           
        'meta_key' => 'transmisie',
        'allow_null' => 'Toate',
        'values' => array(
            'Automata'=> 'Automata',
            'Manuala'=> 'Manuala',
            'Semi-automata'=> 'Semi-automata'
            ), 
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );  

    $args['fields'][] = array( 'type' => 'meta_key', 
        'format' => 'select',
        'class' => 'selectpicker',  
        'pre_html' => '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"><label>Combustibil</label>',
        'post_html' => '</div>',                           
        'meta_key' => 'combustibil',
        'allow_null' => 'Toate',
        'values' => array(
            'Benzina'=> 'Benzina',
            'Diesel'=> 'Diesel',
            'Hibrid'=> 'Hibrid',
            'GPL'=> 'GPL',
            'Electric'=> 'Electric'
            ), 
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );  


    $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'html',
        'value' => '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 range-box" data-range-name="rulaj">');

    $args['fields'][] = array( 'type' => 'meta_key', 
        'meta_key' => 'rulaj',
        'data_type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'inputs' => array(
            array(
                'format' => 'number',
                'value' => '',
                ),
            array(
                'format' => 'number',
                'value' => '',
                )
            )
        );  

    $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'html',
        'value' => '<label>Rulaj:&nbsp; <span id="rulaj-label">1000-100000</span>km</label><input type="text" class="base-input" id="rulaj-input" value=""  data-provide="slider"  data-slider-tooltip="hide" data-slider-min="1000" data-slider-max="200000" data-slider-step="1000" data-slider-value="[1000,100000]"/></div>');




    $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'html',
        'value' => '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 range-box" data-range-name="capacitate_cilindrica">');

    $args['fields'][] = array( 'type' => 'meta_key', 
        'meta_key' => 'capacitate_cilindrica',
        'data_type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'inputs' => array(
            array(
                'format' => 'number',
                'value' => '',
                ),
            array(
                'format' => 'number',
                'value' => '',
                )
            )
        );  

    $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'html',
        'value' => '<label>Motor:&nbsp; <span id="capacitate_cilindrica-label">1000-3000 </span> cm&#179;</label><input type="text" class="base-input" id="capacitate_cilindrica-input" value=""   data-provide="slider"  data-slider-tooltip="hide" data-slider-min="500" data-slider-max="6500" data-slider-step="100" data-slider-value="[1000,3000]"/></div>');

    $args['fields'][] = array( 'type' => 'submit', 
        'value' => 'Cauta',
        'pre_html' => '<div class="col-md-12 text-center">',
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg',

        );

    $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'reset',
        'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-lg',
        'value' => 'Reseteaza',
        'post_html' => '</div>',
        );


    $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'orderby',

        'format' => 'select',
        'orderby_values' =>array(
            'date' => array('label' => 'Date'),
            'pret' => array('label' => 'Pret', 'meta_key' => true, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'),
            )
        );

    $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'order',
        'values' => array('ASC' => 'ASC', 'DESC' => 'DESC'),
        'format' => 'select'
        );



    $args['fields'][] = array( 'type' => 'meta_key', 
        'format' => 'select',
        'meta_key' => 'tip_creditare',
        'allow_null' => 'Toate',
        'values' => array(
            'leasing'=> 'leasing',
            'credit'=> 'credit',
            ), 
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );  


    // $args['debug'] = true;
    // $args['debug_level'] = 'verbose';

    register_wpas_form('easysearch', $args); 

}

add_action('init', 'cautare_simpla');
```